# Sized and using traits as sized objects

Tags: rust

```
struct Point { x: f64, y: f64 }
struct Circle { center: Point, radius: f64 }
struct Square { lowerLeftCorner: Point, side: f64 }

trait ShapeVisitor {
    fn visit_circle(&mut self, c: &Circle);
    fn visit_square(&mut self, c: &Square);
}

trait Shape {
    fn accept<V: ShapeVisitor>(&self, sv: &mut V);
}

impl Shape for Circle {
    fn accept<V: ShapeVisitor>(&self, sv: &mut V) {
        sv.visit_circle(self);
    }
}

impl Shape for Square {
    fn accept<V: ShapeVisitor>(&self, sv: &mut V) {
        sv.visit_square(self);
    }
}
```

So here's a method that computes the total area:

```
fn area(shapes: Vec<Box<dyn Shape>>) -> f64 {
    struct AreaCalculator {
        area: f64,
    }
    impl ShapeVisitor for AreaCalculator {
        fn visit_circle(&mut self, c: &Circle) {
            self.area += std::f64::consts::PI * c.radius * c.radius;
        }
        fn visit_square(&mut self, r: &Square) {
            self.area += r.side * r.side;
        }
    }
    let mut calculator = AreaCalculator { area: 0.0 };
    for shape in shapes {
        (*shape).accept(calculator);
    }
    calculator.area
}
```

And here's an example program

```
fn main() {
    let mut shapes: Vec<Box<dyn Shape>> = Vec::new();
    let p = Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 };
    let circle = Circle { center: p, radius: 12.0 };
    shapes.push(Box::new(circle));

    let area = compute_area(shapes);
    println!("Area {:?}", area);
}
```

Here's the error report:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Shape` cannot be made into an object
  --> visitor.rs:26:25
   |
26 | fn compute_area(shapes: Vec<Box<dyn Shape>>) -> f64 {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Shape` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = help: consider moving `accept` to another trait
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> visitor.rs:11:8
   |
10 | trait Shape {
   |       ----- this trait cannot be made into an object...
11 |     fn accept<V: ShapeVisitor>(&self, sv: &mut V);
   |        ^^^^^^ ...because method `accept` has generic type parameters

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Is there a simple way to rectify it?

Comment: Using `Box<dyn Shape>` (i.e. trait object) contradicts having generic methods in the trait because no fix vtable can be built in advance. If you change `Shape` to dynamic binding instead of generic, i.e. `accept(..., sv: &mut dyn ShapeVisitor)`, it should fix the problem.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to create a trait object, the trait must be [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety). But your `Shape` is not object safe - it has generic type parameters. Removing the type parameters solves the issue:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}
struct Circle {
    center: Point,
    radius: f64,
}
struct Square {
    lowerLeftCorner: Point,
    side: f64,
}

trait ShapeVisitor {
    fn visit_circle(&mut self, c: &Circle);
    fn visit_square(&mut self, c: &Square);
}

trait Shape {
    fn accept(&self, sv: &mut dyn ShapeVisitor);
}

impl Shape for Circle {
    fn accept(&self, sv: &mut dyn ShapeVisitor) {
        sv.visit_circle(self);
    }
}

impl Shape for Square {
    fn accept(&self, sv: &mut dyn ShapeVisitor) {
        sv.visit_square(self);
    }
}

fn area(shapes: Vec<Box<dyn Shape>>) -> f64 {
    struct AreaCalculator {
        area: f64,
    }
    impl ShapeVisitor for AreaCalculator {
        fn visit_circle(&mut self, c: &Circle) {
            self.area += std::f64::consts::PI * c.radius * c.radius;
        }
        fn visit_square(&mut self, r: &Square) {
            self.area += r.side * r.side;
        }
    }
    let mut calculator = AreaCalculator { area: 0.0 };
    for shape in shapes {
        shape.accept(&mut calculator);
    }
    calculator.area
}

fn main() {
    let mut shapes: Vec<Box<dyn Shape>> = Vec::new();
    let p = Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 };
    let circle = Circle {
        center: p,
        radius: 1.0,
    };
    shapes.push(Box::new(circle));
    shapes.push(Box::new(Square {
        lowerLeftCorner: p,
        side: 10.0,
    }));

    let area = area(shapes);
    println!("Area {:?}", area);
}
```